# Android horizontal scrolling container like Gallery

Tags: android, scroll, gallery, centering, horizontal-scrolling

First of all, sorry for my bad english. Hope to understand about that.

Please check below url what I want to do.
[image]

I want to make horizontal scroll viewer like Gallery. But Gallery is deprecated now. So I am going to find other scrollable container such as HorizontalScrollView or HorizontalListView instead of Gallery.

Scrollable container should have property for center-locking, velocity and every child item's width can be able to adjusted dynamically.

I think we can use HorizontalListView or HorizontalScrollView, ViewPager.
But there are issues with them.
HorizontalListView or HorizontalScrollView doesn't have "center-locked" function and ViewPager doesn't have veolocity function. I researched VeolocityViewPager also, but there is no touch event handler for child items.

Best example of this is pulse news reader :- https://market.android.com/details?id=com.alphonso.pulse

Comment: Check [this project](https://github.com/ysamlan/horizontalpager) on github. It should help you with horizontal scrolling.

Comment: I just found the way myself.
Please use EcoGallery project on the github.
https://github.com/falnatsheh/EcoGallery