# Slide Content Horizontally Within a View

Tags: android

I have an application with a top and bottom menu bar in the view. In between these two bars I have an image with text. When a new image comes in I want to push the current image to the left ("off screen") and display the new image with text.

However, how do I allow sliding back to the previous images with figure gesture effects? Is this something similar to sliding the whole view using ViewPager and Fragments, but only doing part of the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As gallery is deprecated, I did some research and found ViewPager. Using the example on the developer site, I was able to create exactly what I wanted.

Link: [Using ViewPager for Screen Slides](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are loaking for is [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) which will allow you to add the images in it programatically and will scroll horizontally.

Comment: Can this gallery also use text within the view? I can only find examples with images only.

Comment: yes you can..by using the custom adapter class in the gallery

Answer (score 0):

try using horizontal scroll gallery.

there's lots of examples in the web.

[similar question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050190/android-horizontal-scrolling-container-like-gallery)

two examples in git for that. [first](https://github.com/ysamlan/horizontalpager) , [second](https://github.com/falnatsheh/EcoGallery)

hope that's what you're looking for.